# IntelliJ (or Webstorm) does not recognise imports from systemJs

Tags: intellij-idea, import, webstorm

I do not understand how I can make IntelliJ understand that my library was mapped with SystemJS. So I get a red wavy line under my import, like the following image illustrates:

[image: intellij-error]

However, the module is loaded correctly and I can use it, i.e. the website is working. The `@angular/core` seems to be recognised. I use the following mapping in `system.config.js`:

```
var map = {
    'app':                        '/ng2experiments/app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   '/ng2experiments/node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/ng2experiments/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '/ng2experiments/node_modules/rxjs',
    'notifications':              '/ng2experiments/node_modules/angular2-notifications'
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'notifications':              { main: 'components.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

Why is it `@angular/core` gets recognised but not `notifications`?

I found the answer during writing the question. I'll post it anyways as Q&A because other people might find it useful.

Comment: I have the same issue and was wondering if you ever got this working without having to match the names?

Answer (score 2):

It's because `@angular/core` is the actual folder name, while `notifications` is not (it's called angular2-notifications). IntelliJ / Webstorm knows nothing about SystemJs. An easy way to solve this is to change the mapping in SystemJs to use the same name as your folder. In this case:

```
var map = {
    'app':                        '/ng2experiments/app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   '/ng2experiments/node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': '/ng2experiments/node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       '/ng2experiments/node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-notifications':     '/ng2experiments/node_modules/angular2-notifications'
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-notifications':     { main: 'components.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

IntelliJ / Webstorm should check out of the box for all the folder names, so it then recognises the module:

[image: intellij solved]

Comment: you can also use typescript@next (1.9) with path mappings instead

Comment: Thanks for the hint, can you maybe elaborate a bit?